# Save angular gridster in local storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gridster

I would like to save angular gridster (position, size, and order of each item ) in local storage and after in database and retrieve stored positions at the page loading. 
I have found something for gridster https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js/issues/111    but  nothing for angular gridster.
Could help me please ? Thank you

```
 vm.gridsterOptions = {
    columns: 4,
    mobileModeEnabled: true,
    draggable: {
      enabled: true, // whether dragging items is supported
      handle: '.H', // optional selector for drag handle
      stop: function(event, $element, widget) {         

      }
    },
    resizable: {
      enabled: true,
      stop: function (e, ui, $widget) {          

      },
      handles: ['n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'ne', 'se', 'sw', 'nw'],


    },
  };
```

Here is my Html

```
 <div gridster="test.gridsterOptions" class="gridster-ready">
        <li class="my-class" gridster-item ng-repeat="datas in     test.chartDataArray "  >

             <highchart  id="container" style="width:100%;height:88%;margin: 0 auto" config="datas" ></highchart>

        </li>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to go about this is to create a service that functions to save and retrieve widget data from local storage. Inject this service into your dashboard controller and you should be able to save the widget data locally. Here's an example of a "widgetmanager" service that would save to local storage:

```
angular.module('app')
    .service('WidgetsManager', widgetsManagerService);

    function widgetsManagerService() {
        return {
        getWidgets: function () {
            return angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem('widgets')) || [];
        },
        setWidgets: function (widgets) {
            return localStorage.setItem('widgets', angular.toJson(widgets));
        },
        clearWidgets: function () {
            return localStorage.removeItem('widgets');
        },
    };
}
```

This would work if your app module was called "app" and you could inject the service like so:

```
angular.module('app').controller('DashboardController', 
['WidgetsManager', dshaboardContoller]);

function dashboardController(WidgetsManager){
    //whatever code. accessing widget manager functions would be preceded by the
    //WidgetManager service like so

    var widgets = WidgetsManager.getWidgets()
}
```

There are a number of ways to inject the service but this is just how ive done it. Good luck, hope this helps!